# Is jupyter reliable enough to run a small web server?

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook, backend

I'm a firmware engineer and a newbie to web development.

I was recently tasked with adding functionality to our internal business systems at the request of our sales team. Any modification to an existing system must be approved by the system administrator each time. Since there is no separate test system, it is risky to develop directly on the system.

Fortunately, the system supports external communication via REST APIs. I decided to configure a web server to implement the functionality.

The features we want to implement are:

1. Provide UI via a simple webpage
2. Receive, process, and send data via a REST API

For security reasons, I need to use only the internal network. Therefore, I have the following options to build a web server:

1. Get a virtual machine instance
2. Get a Jupyter lab page, similar to a Google Colab page.

I know that getting a VM Instance gives me more freedom to do more things. However, VM Instances have a very cumbersome application process, whereas Jupyter is much simpler.

---

From here, it's the body.

- I want to run a web server via ipynb script.
- The webpage will have fewer than 100 concurrent users. The amount of data to process is also small, ranging from a few KB to a few MB per query.
- I think I'll use django, but I'm not sure. I could just use the built-in modules only.
- Sales teams, of course, don't have programmers. If the server dies often, the team leader will be angry, and I'll be sad.

If I run a web server for a long time through an ipynb script on a Jupyter lab, what problems can I expect? I am only interested in stability issues. Other issues such as port opening can be excluded.

e.g.)

- Jupyter might leak RAM and eventually shut down.
- Performance might be very low, and the script might terminate when the number of visitors to the web page exceeds 10.
- ipynb is not intended for long-term use; the server will automatically shut down after a few hours.

And can you tell me a solution?

e.g.) There are auto-restart option for jupyter somewhere.

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: Jupyter is really meant as a tool for interactively exploring code and data. I would not recommend it for running your business logic. If your only alternative for hosting is to get a virtual machine instance, you should do that.

Comment: This is not a programming-related comment, but one about how organisations work: if getting a VM is difficult, and your sales team are the people requesting the functionality, explain to them why any other solution is suboptimal, and enlist them to help you provide the justification for getting a virtual machine in place.

Comment: @larsks: That's exactly what I'm worried about right now. I'm wondering if there are any factors that make code that runs in Jupyter less durable than code that runs in the terminal as a background process.

Comment: @slothrop: Unfortunately, "explaining to them" is one of the "cumbersome application processes." I spent days creating PowerPoint presentations and giving talks to convince non-developers that their existing system could not be modified and that they needed an additional server.

Comment: @slothrop:Additional tasks for VM is following:

1. Convincing team that they need a periodic budget drain (Jupyter is free).
2. Writing a lengthy report on how we plan to build and operate the VM (even have to write a plan for redundancy - all I need is a simple web server!).
3. Going through multiple rounds of approvals (if rejected, we have to revise the report and start over).

If a VM is essential, I should do it. But if it's optional, I really don't want to.

Comment: Sorry to hear, sounds painful!

Comment: Even for the simplest web server, Jupyter is not a good option. Any simple/basic web server will do, and you could run it on the same machine you were planning on running jupyter anyways.

Comment: @slothrop I'm eager to finish this project quickly so I can get back to my real job, FW development

Comment: @eventHandler Is Jupyter such a bad option? As I said, I'd like to know the reason for that. Although we are also considering a local client that can communicate with the system. However, the design requested by the team is a webpage.

Comment: The way I see it, you would spend more or less the same time building and running a jupyter notebook compared to the time spent running a basic web server. In fact, the web server might be easier to run because there're plenty of code samples.

Comment: @eventHandler I can't understand what you're trying to say. Why should I consider the time it takes to set up Jupyter? I already have my own development environment and I'm already making web server and I'm already implementing features.  My only question is, if I run my web server on Jupyter, will it die faster than if I run it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a small web server from the Jupyter Notebook. Is it a good practice? No.

Do you want to start a web server just to make REST endpoint for your code in the notebook?

For running notebook as REST endpoint please check Jupyter Kernel Gateway https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - you can create REST endpoints in the notebook.

For sharing notebooks you can check Mercury framework https://github.com/mljar/mercury - you can share notebooks as interactive web apps. There is a plan to support notebooks as REST API as well (GitHub [issue](https://github.com/mljar/mercury/issues/316) for tracking progress).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The links you provided will be very helpful for my project.
By the way, could you please explain the reason why it is not a good practice? That is my main concern.

Comment: It is hard to manage server deployed directly from Jupyter Notebook. You need to manually start a cell with server code. How would you perform restarts? I only see examples of starting web server in Jupyter Notebook for few minutes, for demo purposes. I'm using supervisord demon for managing deployed servers on the machine - to have automatic restarts.

Comment: I am currently in the feature implementation phase, and I have not yet considered management. However, if things like auto restart are not possible with Jupyter, then that would be a enough reason for me to switch to using a VM.